# onPostExecute not running

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I've got a separate class (not an Activity) to manage an Image with its properties.

In this class (Image.class) I also created an AsynkTask to download a bitmap from the web.
Everything works fine, except the fact that the AsyncTask keeps running, without triggering the onPostExecute() method.

Can someone help me, please?

I instantiate this class in the Main Activity, inside a loop.

```
public class InstaImage {

public URL thumbUrl;
public URL lowresUrl;
public URL standardresUrl;

private URL url;
private Bitmap bmp;

public InstaImage(URL _thumb, URL _low, URL _standard ) {
    this.thumbUrl = _thumb;
    this.lowresUrl = _low;
    this.standardresUrl = _standard;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String resolution) {

    switch(resolution) {
        case "thumb":
            url = thumbUrl;
            break;

        case "low":
            url = lowresUrl;
            break;

        case "standard":
            url = standardresUrl;
            break;
    }

    DownloadImageTask dit = new DownloadImageTask();

    dit.execute();

    // --- TEST ASYNC STATUS ---
    while(dit != null) {

        if(dit.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            Log.i("ASYNC", "END2!!");
            break;
        }
        else {
            Log.w("ASYNC WAITING", dit.getStatus().toString());
        }
    }

    // --- END TEST ASYNC STATUS ---

    return bmp;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    URLConnection conn = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    Bitmap _bmp = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.i("ASYNC","STARTING!!");
        try {
            conn = url.openConnection();

            if (conn != null) {

                in = conn.getInputStream();

                _bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("ASYNC","END0!!");

        return _bmp;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("ASYNC","END1!!");
        bmp = result;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `while(dit != null)` - how would `dit` ever become null?

Comment: a by force _true_ argument to keep the code running.. @michele, do you get a caught exception??

Comment: that's **very** obscure. Just write `while( true )`

Comment: why is `onPostExecute` not marked as `@Override`?

Comment: You might have to let us know what the code is actually outputting because you're vague assertion that the 'AsyncTask keeps running' doesn't help us narrow down the issue, or give us any certainty that it is.

Comment: @Andy while(true) raises the use of my cpu of almost 50%.

Comment: @Andy the code is not outputting. The onPostExecute function is never executed.

Comment: Sir, please read about async task from the official site, and add changes the required changes ok?

Comment: Thanks to the gentle and constructive answer given from @Andy and re-examining the docs I got to my problem and solved it, extending the ImageviewClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of how threads work. You are using an asynchronous call and then busy-waiting for it to finish.

```
// --- TEST ASYNC STATUS ---
while(dit != null) {

    if(dit.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        Log.i("ASYNC", "END2!!");
        break;
    }
    else {
        Log.w("ASYNC WAITING", dit.getStatus().toString());
    }
}

// --- END TEST ASYNC STATUS ---

return bmp;
```

Sorry, but you probably need to do some reading on the topic.

I'd suggest making a class `InstaImageView extends ImageView` and add an asynchronous URI loader inside that. I'm sure this code has been written a thousand times. You could just copy it if you don't understand threads, and asynchronous programming.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to asyncronous programming. That's why I'm trying to figure out my fault. 

The AsyncTask was handled before inside the Main Activity class.

Comment: But then I needed a Class with specific properties for the image and I found logic to let this new class handle the download of the image, as being part of it.
I think my fault was to call the Asynk process from a class that doesn't extend any View, as you say.
I decided to put the while loop test just after I saw after many tries that the onPostExecute method (even with the @Override mark) was never been triggered.@Andy

Answer (score -1):

why you returned from doInBackground fuction?

return _bmp; // No need return here
//Result will auto pass to onPostExcute()

Comment: Because the doInBackground gives me a missing return statement error if I don't do it.